# Need to update cordova in my current sencha app

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I need help. My current app compile with Cordova 3.5 version. Google Mail in my publisher mail that

> Google Play warning: You are using a vulnerable versions of Apache
>   Cordova

So, I need to update Cordova version in my current Sencha app. Otherwise I am not able to upload app in Google Play store, I try to update Cordova using "`cordova platform update android`". After that am not able to create build it stuck in

> [INF] Processing Build Descriptor : default

Please help me I am new in Sencha touch development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will update your project:

1. `npm install -g cordova` (Will update cordova, use sudo if you are in Linux or Mac OS X)
2. Navigate to your project
3. Type `cordova platform rm android`
4. Type `cordova platform add android`

Comment: Thanks Buddy , you save my day.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm update -g cordova
cordova platform update android
```